# Django Rest Serializer Nested Fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am attempting to do a double nested response but the code isn't working.

I am retrieving my objects by a filter with a field and not an id or pk.

Probably unneeded but on the frontend i use `{this.state.profiles[0].title}` as there will ever only be one response since the `slug` field i use to query is a unique field in the database.

In the VideoProduct(models.Model) below, I have profile OneToOneField.  I have that as a tester to see if i could just get a nested response, but that wouldn't work either.

Models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class VideoProduct(models.Model):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class ProfileProduct(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video_product = models.ForeignKey(VideoProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('profile', 'video_product')
```

Views.py:

```
class VideoProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = VideoProduct.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideoProductSerializer

class ProfileProductsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ProfileProduct.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileProductsSerializer

class ProfileBySlug(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileBySlugSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.request.query_params.get('slug', None)
        queryset = Profile.objects.filter(slug=slug)
        if slug is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(slug=slug)
        return queryset
```

Serializers:

```
class VideoProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VideoProduct
        fields = ['id']

class ProfileProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    video_product = VideoProductSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProfileProduct
        fields = ['id', 'video_product']
    
class ProfileBySlugSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile_products = ProfileProductsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'description', 'slug', 'image', 'status', 'profile_products']
```

VideoProduct is just one of many types of products but keeping this slim as possible.

urls.py:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'video_product', views.VideoProductViewSet, basename='r'video_product')
router.register(r'profile_products', views.ProfileProductsViewSet, basename='profile_products')

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api/v1/profile/', views.ProfileBySlug.as_view(), name='profile'),
    ...
]
```

My desired outcome is to have something like:

```
profile: {
    id: 1,
    title: "Title",
    profile_products: [{
        video_product: {
            id: 1,
            title: "video title"
        }
    }]
}
```

Able to get it this way:

```
profile_products_set = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_profile_products')

def get_profile_products(self, profile):
    qs = ProfileProduct.objects.filter(profile=profile)
    print(qs)
    serializer = ProfileProductsSerializer(instance=qs, many=True)
    return serializer.data
```

Although, my issue now is iterating it through React due to the null fields (a ProfileProduct can only hve one related field).  I opted out using Generic Foriegn Keys due to an article i read saying its not too scalable.

Comment: `profile_products` ***must*** be a ***`list`*** (an array) , but, In your desired output, it has shown as an ***`dict`*** ( an object ) which doesn't make any sense

Comment: Desired output is an example, and likely wrong.  I just want to at least get the associations and I'm not.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
class ProfileBySlugSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile_products = ProfileProductsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'description', 'slug', 'image', 'status', 'profile_products']
    profile_products = serializers.SerializerMethodField("get_profile_products")
    
    def get_profile_products(self, args):
        return [{"id": i.video_product.id, "title": i.video_product.title} for i in args.profile_products.all()]
```

Comment: thanks, I ended up doing similar:... I have posted in my edit.  Feel free to give me opinion